# laravel and tinymce image upload integration

Tags: laravel, tinymce, justboil.me

I am using TinyMCE as text editor in my projects for the image upload i use the justboil.me(jbimages) plugin when i use this with laravel the text editor works fine but i can not upload any image the jbimages plugin returns 404 error from these tow  http://example.com/js/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/upload/english http://example.com/js/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/blank
i think this is because of routing how can i resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after messing with the plugin i found maybe the only way is change some of the html code
step 1:
change dialog-v4.htm form action to http://example.com/public/js/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/upload/english
then the iframe src to http://example.com/public/js/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/blank
step 2:
change $config['img_path'] to '/public/your_image_directory' in config.php file

if anyone has a cleaner solution i will be happy to see